# iOS - UISearchBar dynamic search results doesn't work when typed quickly (swift)

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, uisearchbar

What I want is a searchbar that updates the tableview with usernames as every character is entered into the searchbar by the user. When the user deletes (backspaces) all the characters in the searchbar, ie the searchbar is empty, I want the tableview to be display no usernames and be empty.

I have a semi functioning UISearchbar that searches for usernames (Parse backend). It works fine when I type character by character in the searchbar slowly.

However, when I type quickly, the search results are a bit off - it shows me usernames from characters that were previously entered. For eg: if I enter 'nik' quickly it still shows me usernames with 'ni' in them. Also, when I backspace quickly until there are no characters in the searchbar, it still shows me certain usernames.

Again, it works fine when I enter characters in slowly, but I feel like it isn't very efficient. I have tried all sorts of things but nothing has worked well so far. I have added the relevant code below, let me know if you need more information.

```
    // called when keyboard search button pressed
func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {

    let searchString = searchBar.text;

    if (searchString != "") {
        //do load users
        loadUsers(searchText: searchString!);
        print("called from searchBarSearchButtonClicked");
    }

}

// called when cancel button pressed
func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {

    searchBar.text = "";

    //hide tableview maybe?!
    //searchTableView.isHidden = true;

}

func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
    let searchString: String = (searchController.searchBar.text)!;


    /*if (searchString == "" && !searchActive) {
        searchResults.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false);
        searchTableView.reloadData();
        print("test");
    }*/

    if (searchString != "" && !self.searchActive) {
        loadUsers(searchText: searchString);
        print("called from updateResults");
    }

    if (searchString == "") {
        searchResults.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false);
        searchTableView.reloadData();
        print("test");
    }
}


func loadUsers(searchText: String ) {

    if(searchText != "") {


        let usernameQuery = PFUser.query();
        //usernameQuery?.whereKey("username", equalTo: searchText);
        usernameQuery?.whereKey("username", contains: searchText.lowercased());


        let fbUsername = PFUser.query();
        fbUsername?.whereKey("username", contains: searchText);


        let firstnameQuery = PFUser.query();
        //firstnameQuery?.whereKey("last_name", equalTo: searchText)
        firstnameQuery?.whereKey("last_name", contains: searchText);


        let lastnameQuery = PFUser.query();
        //lastnameQuery?.whereKey("first_name", equalTo: searchText);
        lastnameQuery?.whereKey("first_name", contains: searchText);


        let query = PFQuery.orQuery(withSubqueries: [usernameQuery!,fbUsername!, firstnameQuery!, lastnameQuery!]);

        searchActive = true;

        query.findObjectsInBackground { (objects, error) in

            if error != nil {

                print("There was an error getting userlist");

            }

            else {

                if let object = objects {

                    self.searchResults.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false);

                    for object in objects! {

                        let user = object.object(forKey: "username") as! String;
                        self.searchResults.append(user);

                    }

                    //self.searchTableView.reloadData();


                    DispatchQueue.main.async {

                     self.searchTableView.reloadData();

                     //self.userSearchController.searchBar.resignFirstResponder();

                     }

                }

            }

            self.searchActive = false;

        }
    }

}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if(userSearchController.isActive) {

        print(searchResults.count);
        return searchResults.count;

    }

    return 0;
}


public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath);

    if(self.userSearchController.isActive && searchResults.count > indexPath.row) {

        print(searchResults[indexPath.row]);
        cell.textLabel?.text = searchResults[indexPath.row];

    }

    return cell;

}




/*
public func searchBarShouldBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) -> Bool {
    return true;
}

public func searchBarShouldEndEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) -> Bool {
    return true;
}



func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {

        //loadUsers(searchText: (searchBar.text)!);
} */


func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

    if (searchBar.text != "" ) {
        NSObject.cancelPreviousPerformRequests(withTarget: self, selector: #selector(loadUsers(searchText:)), object: searchBar.text! as String);


        perform(#selector(loadUsers(searchText:)), with: searchBar.text! as String, afterDelay: 0.50);


        print("called from textDidChange");

    }
    if (searchBar.text == "") {

        searchResults.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false);
        searchTableView.reloadData();
        print("test2");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by using Timer. The code below waits for one second before calling your function. If a text change occurs in that one second it will invalidate the previous scheduled timer and only do the second one. You can check this by printing the search text in your function.

```
var timer: Timer?

func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        timer?.invalidate() //cancels out previous Timers
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(myFunctionThatDoesServerSearch), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)  
    }
```